# btrfs - data usage in <ERROR> with inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: filesystems, disk-space-utilization, btrfs

I'm attempting to trace down what's using some of the space on my btrfs filesystem. There is a large difference between `btrfs fi du -s /` and `btrfs fi usage /` and the difference seems to be in the `<ERROR>` section when running `btdu`.

How can I trace down what's contributing to this `<ERROR>` usage?

```
# btrfs fi du -s /
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
     5.50GiB     5.50GiB       0.00B  /
```

```
# btrfs fi usage /
Overall:
    Device size:                  20.00GiB
    Device allocated:             12.28GiB
    Device unallocated:            7.72GiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                         11.59GiB
    Free (estimated):              8.22GiB      (min: 8.22GiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.00
    Metadata ratio:                   1.00
    Global reserve:               16.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,single: Size:12.00GiB, Used:11.50GiB
   /dev/sda2      12.00GiB

Metadata,single: Size:256.00MiB, Used:89.03MiB
   /dev/sda2     256.00MiB

System,single: Size:32.00MiB, Used:16.00KiB
   /dev/sda2      32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda2       7.72GiB
```

Relevant btdu output:

```
--- / --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ~12.0 GiB  [##########] /<DATA>  
   ~253.1 MiB [          ]  <METADATA>
   ~32.0 MiB  [          ]  <SYSTEM>
   
   
--- /DATA ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~6.5 GiB [##########] /<ERROR>
    ~2.1 MiB [          ] /<ROOT_TREE>
    ~5.5 GiB [########  ] /@ 
    
    
--- /DATA/ERROR ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~6.0 GiB [##########]  logical ino (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
  ~509.9 MiB [          ]  logical ino (No such file or directory)
```

So my conclusions here is that the actual files on my system are taking up around 5.5GB, and the rest of the usage is from something that btdu reports as Error.

Notes / Things I've tried:

- I have run every flavour of `balance`, `rescue`, `check --repair`, `scrub`  that I could find on any site. No luck.
- I have unmounted all other disks / nfs drives / etc. (No hidden files under mounts.)

Comment: Is it possible that the btrfs "device" size mismatches the physical device size? I.e. the partition / physical disk is 6 GB larger than what btrfs is configured to use.

Comment: Don't think so. The "usage" command above says 20GB, and fdisk -l reports 20GB size on that disk also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, looking at the kernel code and at btdu again, I think I got it.

Your kernel is too old (4.14 or older) and does not support `BTRFS_IOC_LOGICAL_INO_V2`.

The reason why 1) btdu mostly works and 2) these errors are mapped to 6 GB of space is that btdu only uses `BTRFS_IOC_LOGICAL_INO_V2` to perform queries if the first query (which is done with `BTRFS_IOC_LOGICAL_INO` - no `_V2`) produces no results.

I will update btdu to show an appropriate hint for this case.

As for what is consuming these 6 GB of space: most likely they are unreachable parts of partially-used extents. A defragmentation will get rid of them. If you update your kernel, btdu will be able to tell you which files are pinning these extents.

Comment: So you're absolutely right, thank you! I upgraded the OS to get a more recent kernel, and now btdu doesn't show me any errors. It DOES show me that all of my usage is related to unreachable files generated by prometheus, but that's beyond the scope of this question I think.

Comment: I saw this thread a while ago discussing the same topic, perhaps you may find something useful here: https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/lip3dk/unreachable_data_on_btrfs_according_to_btdu/